# How To Invoke Variables To Specify Format Of printf In C Programming

Tags: c, variables, unix, printf

I want to use variables to specify format of `printf` in C programming.

I am quite a C programming newbie, having practiced bash shell scritps though.

In bash scripts, I can use a variable to specify format of `printf` as one below.

```
#!/bin/bash

### Variable
format="%4s%4d %8s\n"

### Main
printf "$format" $1 $2 $3
```

Then, Is there similar way like the above in C programming?

Is it possible in C?

The strings for the `printf` format include characters and numbers.

I have heard C programming uses different declaration for each of them;
i.e. int or char.

Comment: You can even `printf` to a format string that you use in another `printf`.

Comment: Yes, you can, but it is rarely useful to do so.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Although I've understood there are many ways, each line's meaning in code is difficult to understand as of now, because today is still the second from C programming learning start. I will choose the best answer, when I am able to understand sample lines. I appriciate all support from the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there similar way like the above [`format="%4s%4d %8s\n"`] in C programming?
> Is it possible
> in C?

Yes, several ways to both questions.
Among them, you can use [sprintf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm) to prepare the buffer:

```
char format[80] = {0};//create editable char array
int a = 12;
char buf1[] = {"this is string 1"};
char buf2[] = {"this is string 2"};

sprintf(format, "%s", "%4s%4d %8s\n");
printf(format, buf1, val, buf2);
```

Even closer to what you have done in your example ( `format="%4s%4d %8s\n"` ), you can simply define `format` as a [string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-string-literals?view=vs-2019):

```
char *format = "%4s%4d %8s\n";//string literal not editable
```

Or, create an initialized, but editable char array

```
char format[] = {"%4s%4d %8s\n"};//editable, but only up to 
                                 //strlen("%4s%4d %8s\n"); 
                                 //(+ NULL, which is implied when using "...".)
```

Note that C also provides a built in feature to enable run-time setting of precision when outputting floating point numbers:

```
double val = 22.123445677890;
int precision = 3;

printf("%.*f", precision ,  val);
```

Will output `22.123`

Comment: Thank you for yor useful advice. Could I ask one additional question? As my own post for an answer, I used ""  double quotations like "char format[] = "%s\n"; ".  Then your sample code is using {} like "char format[80] = {0};".  Do {} braces have special meaning? Should they be used in such case? Since I am a newbie, I would want to know how they are different.

Comment: @CaptainCookie - Yes, `{0}` is the `C` way to ensure that _all_ elements of an `array` are zeroed when using as an initializer.  There is a great discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201116/645128) about initializations in general, including this one.

Comment: I will check suggested page! Today I could understand the difference single and double quotation in other question. I also want to understand about {}. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can build a format string dynamically:

```
char fmt[20];
int b;
char a[SOME_SIZE];
char c[SOME_SIZE];

...
sprintf( fmt, "%%4s%%4d %%8s\n" ); // need %% to print a literal %, so fmt will contain "%4s%4d %8s\n"
printf( fmt, a, b, c );
```

There are other ways of building a format string dynamically, this is just the most straightforward.

> I have heard C programming uses different declaration for each of them; i.e. int or char.

Yes, each format specifier expects its corresponding argument to have the correct type.  `%d` expects its corresponding argument to have type `int`, `%s` expects its argument to have type `char *`, etc.  If they don't match, then the behavior is *undefined* and you'll likely get weird-looking output.

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve my first purpose thanks to all your support.

I wrote such code below, using a Symbolic Constant or "char anyname[] = string".

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FORMAT "%30s\n" 

int main()
{
    char c_string[] = "You Suceed!";

    printf(FORMAT, c_string);

    return 0;
}

/*
int main()
{
    char format[] = "%s\n"; 
    char c_string[] = "You Suceed!";

    printf(format, c_string);

    return 0;
}
*/
```

I appreciate all your suggestion!